# compute git hash of all *uncommitted* code

Tags: git

Is there a good way to get a git hash that works as follows:

1. if there are no uncommitted changes, return the git hash of the current branch tip (ignoring untracked files), or
2. if there is at least one uncommited change (whether in the staging area or not, but ignoring untracked files), compute the git hash that would result if one ran `git commit -a -m ''`?

*Background:*

I'm writing some development tools that package up builds.  I'd like the build package to include some sort of reasonably-robust and completely automatic version id.  A git SHA1 hash is more than sufficient for my purposes.  Unfortunately, just using `git rev-parse HEAD` isn't sufficient because users will commonly run the build before committing, and thus before `HEAD` is updated.

Comment: Are you sure that you want the hash of the commit? (It's different every time you run it, even with the same files). I assume you're better off creating a new tree object and taking its hash.

Comment: Ideally, the hash would only include the contents and locations of all tracked files, with no timestamp issues that you raise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want the hash of a Git tree object, not that of a commit. A commit hash depends on the commit time and will be different every time you compute it.

To create a new tree object from your working copy you can run the `write-tree` command:

```
git add -u && git write-tree && git reset
```

Note that this will mess up your index (as it will temporarily stage all changes)

Comment: Or, set a temporary alternative index file and use that to write the tree.

Comment: @torek: do you mind clarifying how you'd use a temporary alternative index file?

Comment: Git uses the environment variable `GIT_INDEX_FILE` as the file containing the index.  If not set, the default is `$GIT_DIR/index`.  So if you make an empty temporary file (see `mktemp`), put that in `$GIT_INDEX_FILE`, and do the `add` and `write-tree` ops, then remove the temporary index file, you'll get the tree-hash without modifying the default index file.

Comment: I get fatal: mmap failed: No such device with
(export GIT_INDEX_FILE=/tmp/tmp.XbgWmOdzTT ; git add -u && git write-tree && git reset)

Comment: To fix this: ``savedindex=`git write-tree`; git add .; git write-tree; git read-tree $savedindex``.

Answer (score 15):

Create a temporary index, write the uncommitted changes to it, then get the sha of that tree.

```
cp .git/index /tmp/git_index
export GIT_INDEX_FILE=/tmp/git_index
git add -u
git write-tree
unset GIT_INDEX_FILE
```

This will print out a sha unique to the current state of the git repo including uncommitted changes, but not including new files.

Comment: Sounds like if you want it including new files you just need to swap the `-u` by `-all`

Comment: I assume afterwards we need to restore the old value of GIT_INDEX_FILE?

Comment: @donquixote Nice catch. Yes, I've updated the answer to unset `GIT_INDEX_FILE` as normally it is unset.